# Django Form does not display, gives error that it is unable to match urls

Tags: python, django, forms

With Django, I am trying to display a form to edit content on a page. However I run into the following error when trying to visit the editpage view

> NoReverseMatch at /editpage/CSS/
> Reverse for 'editpage' with keyword arguments '{'topic': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editpage\/(?P[^/]+)\/$']

Where "CSS" here is an example pulled from the link address via str:topic in urls.py.

I think the issue is with my form action in editpage.html, where I reference the editpage url and I have tried numerous combinations but am unable to get it to display. Removing the form allows the link to display with no error. Any help is much appreciated.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("editpage/<str:topic>/", views.editpage, name="editpage"),
]
```

editpage.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit Page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Edit page</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'editpage' topic=topic %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">    
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django import forms
from . import util

class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'topic', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    article = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Existing article', 'class': 'form-control'}))

def editpage(request, topic):  
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", {"form": EditPageForm()
    })
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is a you catch input from browser using urls.py

> path("editpage/str:topic/", views.editpage, name="editpage"),

than it's (str:topic) coming **editpage** funation inside of **urls.py** file. But you don't sent it (str:topic) your **editpage.html** form . That why database don't understend witch **title** need you.

you need to change :-

**views.py**

```
def editpage(request, topic):  
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", {"form": EditPageForm()
    ,"topic":topic})
```

**one more advice :-**

If you use  {{ form.as_p }} inside your **editpage.html** it's look like better

Answer (score 1):

Try this.the problem is that you have forgotten to pass the topic inside the context and from what i see you are not handling correctly the form(you have to make a `GET` and `POST` to handle the form).if you need more help about this let me know.

```
def editpage(request, topic):  
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", {"form": EditPageForm(),"topic":topic})
```

Comment: Thanks Amadou! Yes, it works now. I'll also build in the appropriate form handling. Have a good day ahead!

Comment: @cjuggler i am happy i was able to help you.